# Check if a number or a letter present before a certain Character

Tags: javascript, regex

Good morning,
I want to find out in javascript with a query if a short string is included in a model number. The code now looks like this:

```
(ui.item.Partnumber).includes("C-")
```

But now I want to find out

- if there is a number before the `C`
- and a letter after the `-`.

Unfortunately I can't find anything on the web. Would that be possible with ${..} ? But also for this I found too little that it could help me.
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex will be the best approach (see other answers)

But if you want to get number before and after do this. Use `split` and check the first and second array elements.

```js
var result = ("123C-324").split("C-");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This one could work with different lengths of model numbers. After split I only have the one last and one first sign of the splitted parts. I will also try this! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for those patterns.

The regex says:

> Find a digit (`\d`) followed by `C-` followed by a letter from `[A-Z]`.

If that's the entirety of the string you can bookend the regex with `^` (start of the string) and `$` (end of the string). If you're looking to find uppercase *or* lowercase letters you can use `[A-Za-z]` instead.

```js
const re = /\dC-[A-Z]/;

console.log(re.test('1C-3'));
console.log(re.test('1C-F'));
console.log(re.test('1C3'));
console.log(re.test('1F-3'));
console.log(re.test('6C-V'));
console.log(re.test('3C-T'));
```